# openstackclient: Exception raised: cannot import name redirect_stdout

Tags: python-2.7, openstack

I installed openstackclient:4.0.0 on Python 2.7.5 and getting the below error

Exception raised: cannot import name redirect_stdout

Any thoughts

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, a complete exception trace would have been more helpful.

> The exception which you are getting is due to missing contextlib which
>   is part of python3.
>   Openstackclient is using contextlib in network related operations
>   currently, however not using redirect_stdout.

Looks like you are using a lib which is using redirect_stdout from contextlib. It doesn't seems to be openstackclient.